# Javax Persitence: Query interpetation order

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a in-memory database with 5 elements inside. It is looking like this:

```
(1, '1542'),
(2, '9999'),
(3, '456'),
(4, '456'), 
(5, '21568');
```

Using the [Persistence API's Query object](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html), I am constructing the following query:

```
SELECT c FROM table c WHERE c.secondParam = :secondParam ORDER BY c.id asc AND rownum <= 2;
```

And I get the expected result:

```
+----+-----------------+
| id |   secondParam   |
+----+-----------------+
|  3 |       456       |
|  4 |       456       |
+----+-----------------+
```

However, running the following query (which was in the legacy code I tried to test):

```
SELECT c FROM table c WHERE c.secondParam = :secondParam AND rownum <= 2 ORDER BY c.id asc;
```

Gives no result at all.

Running the first query in a database manager (DBeaver, namely) even gives an error:

```
SQL Error [933] [42000]: ORA-00933: Sql command does not end correctly
```

The second works fine in DBeaver, but does not in my in-memory test.

Is Javax re-ordering the parameters itself in order to make it valid ? What is the difference bewteen the two queries, technically speaking ? Is there any in-depth brewery that this API is doing in order to prioritize the operations ?

Thank you !

Comment: Yeah, the `query.setMaxResults(2)` it the option I was heading towards. I was just curious about why the first would succeed and not the second, considering the API and failure of the "raw" query entered in DBeaver. Thank you for the documentation.

Comment: Outstanding intuition. I can't wrap my head around why the second request works fine in DBeaver, yet does not give me the expected result in my test, but the first one is wrong but passes because H2 makes it valid (however how). Thank you for your clarifications.